# How can I change the location of the default "snap" folder?

Tags: snap

Is it possible to achieve the following operation and move the "snap" foldee into a subdirectory of "Home"?

**Example:**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging from the response to LP: [#1575053](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1575053), I don't believe it's possible to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently a quick solution is

1. You can create a `.hidden` file inside home folder
2. Edit the `.hidden` file in your favourite editor (nono, vim, emacs)
3. Add a line called `snap` and save

(or)

1. You can run this command to paste snap to `.hidden` file

```
echo "snap" >> .hidden
```

This will hide the folder. (But if you are using terminal it will be still there)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible at the moment. There's a lot of reasons why this is pretty hard and although some of those can be addressed this is not on the roadmap at this time. We simply need to address more fundamental problems before being able to work on this.

If you are an interested in this topic please get in touch with me (I'm zyga on #snappy IRC) and we can talk about what it might take to support that.

I understand the desire to customize the environment so that it feels good but this is one of those things that were just too costly do to early and I hope that you understand this.

Comment: Thanks! For now I simply set this folder to hidden in Nautilus. :-)

Comment: I really really hope it makes its way up the priority list soon. The comments on that Launchpad bug make it pretty clear that there are plenty of people out there who would like this fixed.